# Use of strcmp() to read data from a client not working as expected

Tags: c, strcmp, strncmp

I am following an exercise where I need to set up networking between a client and server and have them "talk". I need to check for specific responses from the client and then have the server act accordingly. To read data from the client, I am using a function which calls recv() in a loop, until either a '\n' character, or there are no more bytes to read. When the loop ends, the last character in the array is set to a '\0'. When the function is done, I expect to get a null terminated string which I can then use in a comparison. 
Here is the function -

```
int read_in(int socket, char *buf, int len) {
    char *s = buf;
    int slen = len;
    int c = recv(socket, s, slen, 0);
    while((c>0) && (s[c-1]!='\n')) {
        s+=c; slen-=c;
        c = recv(socket, s, slen, 0);
    }
    if (c<0) {
        return c;
    } else if (c==0) {
        buf[0] = '\0';
    } else {
        s[c-1] = '\0';
    }
    return len-slen;
}
```

Now, I wait for a connection, declare an array named "buf" to store what I read with the above function and then compare 2 strings with strcmp()

```
int connect_d = accept(listener_d, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &address_size);
char buf[255];
read_in(connect_d, buf, sizeof(buf));
if (strcmp("Hello\0", buf) == 0) {
    puts("Hello");
} else {
    puts("Not Hello");
}
```

I believe that the "buf" string contains "Hello\0" and therefore the comparison should be successful. But its not. I can't figure out why though. If however, I use strncmp() to compare the first 5 bytes of the 2 strings, the comparison passes. But when I compare the first 6 bytes, it fails. I am wondering what gets stored in the 6th byte position that fails it.

Comment: String literals are guaranteed to be properly null terminated. No need for the null terminating character.

Comment: If you know the length of the string you should use __strncmp__ with the correct length (here 5 I guess for "hello" no need for the "\0") but so you don't take care of what's there after buf[4]. [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) is a good use of strcmp and [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/) of strncmp.

Comment: What makes you think `buf` contains `"Hello\0"`? `strcmp` failing is a pretty strong indication that `buf` in fact **doesn't** contain what you think it does.

Comment: why do you use `sizeof(ans)` and not `sizeof(buf)`?

Comment: The test `s[c-1] != '\n'` is incorrect if the server sends more than one line at once, as in `"hello\nworld"`. To be sure you're not missing a line, you should be using `memchr` or `strchr` to locate the newline in the input you've read.

Comment: @falloutboy That was a typo

Comment: @user4815162342 This is what I type at the telnet prompt - Hello followed by the line return. The test may fail in cases where the client sends multiple lines, but that's not the case here.

Comment: maybe the client sends `\r\n` so your output would be `Hello\r\0`

Comment: The read_in() reads `Hello\r` from the `Hello\r\n` and then replaces the last character in `Hello\r` with '\0' making it `Hello\0`. At least in theory, that's what the code does.

Comment: the loop ends, when `s[c-1] == '\n'` and then sets `s[c-1] = '\0'`, so if there was a `\r\n` before, there will be `\r\0` at the end.

Comment: Your logic is unfortunately flawed: the fact that you type `Hello` at the telnet prompt is no guarantee that `Hello` ends up in `buf`. You could have a bug in `read_in()` or elsewhere in the program that incorrectly fills up `buf`, or `telnet` (as others pointed out) `telnet` could be sending the additional carriage-return character over the wire. On the other hand, `strcmp(buf, "Hello")` returning non-zero is pretty much a guarantee that `buf`, at that point, does not begin with `Hello\0`.

Comment: Telnet definitly sends `\r\n`, at least if it conforms the relvant RFC.

Comment: You did not mention if the socket is set to blocking or nonblocking.  This makes a significant difference in the code.  You would be much better off, although it is slower, to, in a loop that exits on timeout or '\n' using the select() function and only read one char at a time.  If the socket is nonblocking and the return is 0 bytes, that is not an error.

Comment: regarding this line: if (strcmp("Hello\0", buf) == 0) {,  strcmp stops at the first '\0' so the compare will never match.  it should be if (strcmp("Hello", buf) == 0) {  and even then, it will only match if the capitalization is the same.

Comment: regarding the line: char buf[255];  this should be: char buf[255] = {0};  This will mean the lines:     } else if (c==0) {
        buf[0] = '\0';
    } else {
        s[c-1] = '\0'; can be eliminated.

Comment: regarding this line: read_in(connect_d, buf, sizeof(buf));, the function read_in() returns an indication of i/o error, or 0 or number of bytes read.  The return code is not being checked, so any failures are not detected.  Also, if socket flag 'nonblocking' is set, then the function read_in exits without actually reading the input. (yet another reason to use select() with a timeout and only read one char at a time.)

Comment: regarding the lines: if (strcmp("Hello\0", buf) == 0) {
    puts("Hello");  if you printf() buf, before the 'if' you will see what is actually in buf.  and replace 'puts("Hello")' with 'puts(buf)' to display the actual read value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some possibilities:

1. In `read_in()` you add NUL to `buf` if the last character you're read is `'\n'` but if you've read 0 bytes in the last call of `recv()`, you do `buf[0] = '\0';`. You should change that to `s[0] = '\0';` to keep what you have read before (to be honest, if that was what happened in your case, `strncmp("Hello", buf, 5)` wouldn't work either, but I wanted to point that problem out anyway)
2. if the client sends more then one line, you could receive sth. like `"Hello\nWorld\n"` in a single call of `read_in()` and you would set `buf` to `"Hello\nWorld"`
3. is it a windows client? in that case, you could receive `"Hello\r\n"` so you had so set `c[s-2]` to `'\0'` (be careful, both characters are maybe received by different calls of `recv()`)
4. maybe the client doesn't send `"Hello\n"` but `"Hello \n"` ore something like that

Just add a `printf()` (eg. `printf( "buf[5] = %x\n", buf[5] & 0xff );`) to see what exactly you have received

**Edit**

now that we know, that the server receives `"Hallo\r\n"`, I would suggest you add that to the end of `read_in()` (in case of `c >= 0`):

```
 int buflen = strlen( buf );
 if( buflen > 0 && buf[buflen-1] == '\r' )
      buf[buflen-1] = '\0';
```

Comment: The Telnet client is on a Linux box

Comment: then you should really add a `printf()` to see what telnet decided to send (btw: apart from what you've said in your last comment to the question, your code would **not** eliminate `'\r'`, only `'\n'`)

Comment: `printf("buf[5] = %x\n", buf[5] & 0xff);` returns `ans[5] = d`

Comment: Here we are -- 0x0d == '\r', so you have to eliminate '\r' and '\n'

Comment: `strlen` could fail if `buf` isn't null terminated.

Comment: @staticx `buf` is always NUL terminated if reading was successful. I've clearified my suggestion

Answer (score -2):

Most likely the server sent you just five bytes 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' and not a zero byte. strcmp expects strings that end in a zero byte (and the C compiler adds a zero byte to a string literal, so your "Hello\0" is quite pointless).

You want to check that the number of bytes returned is 5, and that memcmp ("Hello", buf, 5) returns 0. You need to check the number of bytes returned separately, otherwise a reply like "Hello my friend" would be interpreted as "Hello".

Comment: The OP is clearly already aware of this - the `read_in` function does attempt to NUL-terminate the received string.